# How to set up LndHub on top of RaspiBolt ir RaspiBlitz?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

My goal is to support multiple LN clients without having to run a full node for each client.

How to set up [LndHub](http://lndhub.io/) on top of RaspiBolt or RaspiBlitz?

Answer (score 1):

The RaspiBlitz is running LND. So, when you look at https://github.com/BlueWallet/LndHub, you will find that you only need to install Redis and then you can set up LndHub.io as in their documentation:

> ```
> git clone git@github.com:BlueWallet/LndHub.git
> cd LndHub
> npm i
> ```
>
> Install `bitcoind`, `lnd` and `redis`. Edit `config.js` and set it up correctly. Copy `admin.macaroon` and `tls.cert` in root folder of LndHub.

You can do all of that via `ssh` on your RaspiBlitz.

Answer (score 0):

See also related github issue - https://github.com/BlueWallet/LndHub/issues/39.